# Injecting IHostingEnvironment in Razor Views in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am reading website meta tags from `XML` file which is stored in `wwwroot` folder. The way to access it is using `IHostingEnvironment` but since it's on shared `_layout` how do i inject it. I get error

> "The name IHostingEnvironment doesn't exist in current context.

is there a way to set meta tags using `XML` for `_layout` so it appears in all `Asp.Net` pages that share this `_layout`.

**_layout.cshtml**

```
@using Jaeger.Services
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
@inject MenuMasterService menus
@using System.Xml.Linq;

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="de">

    <head>
        @{

            var filepath = IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath.ToString() + @"\meta-data.xml";
            XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
            //Run query
            IEnumerable<XElement> metaList = xmlDoc.Root.Elements("meta");

            var result = from a in metaList
                         select new
                         {
                             title = a.Element("title").Value.Trim(),
                             description = a.Element("description").Value.Trim(),
                             keywords = a.Element("keywords").Value.Trim()
                         };
            //jaeger
            var xml_tilte = result.ElementAt(0).title;
            var xml_desc = result.ElementAt(0).description;

        }

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        @*<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">*@
        <title>@ViewData["Title"] - @xml_tilte</title>
        <meta name="description" content="@xml_desc">


.....
```

Comment: why not write a custom service to handle it - that way its super testable!

Comment: thanks @DanielA.White i will look into that, I am a beginner in dotnet so i will have to look into that. But i was wondering if there is any way to make current code work.

Comment: thank you, i was able to do what i wanted using service, it's much cleaner way than what i previously had done. Thank you for suggestion @DanielA.White

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Daniel A. White suggestion, i wrote a custom service and was able to read file. Adding  custom service here, it might help anyone else.

**MetaReaderService.cs**

```
namespace Test.Services
{
    public class MetaReaderService
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;

        public MetaReaderService(IHostingEnvironment environment)
        {
            _env = environment;
        }

        public IEnumerable<MetaDataXMLModel> GetMetaData()
        {

            var filepath = _env.ContentRootPath.ToString() + @"\meta-data.xml";
            XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
            //Run query
            IEnumerable<XElement> metaList = xmlDoc.Root.Elements("meta");

            var result = from a in metaList
                         select new MetaDataXMLModel
                         {
                             title = a.Element("title").Value.Trim(),
                             description = a.Element("description").Value.Trim(),
                             keywords = a.Element("keywords").Value.Trim()
                         };
            
            return result;
      }


    }

    public class MetaDataXMLModel
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }

        public string keywords { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@using Test.Services
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject MetaReaderService metaReaderXml
@inject MenuMasterService menus
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    @{
        @Html.Raw(ViewData["MetaData"]);

        // loading meta title, description and keyword
        var result = metaReaderXml.GetMetaData();
    }

    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - @result.ElementAt(0).title</title>
    <meta name="description" content=" @result.ElementAt(0).description ">
    <meta name="keywords" content=" @result.ElementAt(0).keywords ">

...
```

more detail about custom services [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)